# Linq query list contains a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 a class's:

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}

public class ObjectB
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public List<ObjectA> ListOfObjectA;
}
```

So I have two lists: One of ObjectB (ListObjectB) and Another contains a list of id's of ObjectA (called  ListOfIdsA).
If this i want to get a list of ObjectB where ObjectB.ListOfObjectA is in the ListOfIdsA.

My first (and wrong) approach was

```
ListObjectB.Where(p=> ListOfIdsA.Contains(p.ListOfObjectA.Select(b=>b.Id)))
```

But this obviously throws an exception. I google it, stackoverflowed, but I'm thinking that my search skills aren't going so well in this, can anybody give a ninja awser of this? 
(Prefereably in lambda expression)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Are you trying to get a list of ObjectBs where *all* of the ObjectAs are in ListOfIdsA, or *any* of them?

I think you want either:

```
ListObjectB.Where(p => p.ListOfObjectA.Any(x => ListOfIdsA.Contains(x.Id)))
```

or

```
ListObjectB.Where(p => p.ListOfObjectA.All(x => ListOfIdsA.Contains(x.Id)))
```

(You may well want to make `ListOfIdsA` a `HashSet<string>` if it's of significant size, btw.)

Comment: Learn something new every day...for some reason I was thinking Extension methods were the way to solve this one.

Comment: I want it any of them. Thx for the prompt response (it was my first question in here, and damn, that was fast!)

Comment: @Justin: Well Where, All and Any *are* extension methods :)

Comment: Doh! Poorly worded comment. I was referring to hand rolling my own Extension Methods.

Comment: @Justin: Ah - that does indeed make more sense :)

Comment: @JonSkeet this may warrant a separate question, but what if I wanted where ALL of ObjectA's are in ListOfIdsA? I tried "All", but seems like that filter was basically not applied

Comment: @BZ: That's already what the query is doing. I think another question (with a short but complete example) probably would be useful, yes.

Comment: I think we should add a .ToList() to end of the above lines... Besides I don't see the differnece between two lines!

Comment: @SharifYazdian: One uses `All` and one uses `Any`. But there's no need to use `ToList()` unless you actually need to materialize the results.