# Populate List Where Contains values (or objects) from another list

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, entity-framework

I want to populate a list where a value in the object is in another list I've already populated. Please see below:

```
//Populate first object
List<Object1> listObject1 = da.dbsetObject1.Where(p=>p.ID.Equals(SomeID)).ToList();

//Populate second object - what I want to do but can't figure out
List<Object2> listObject2 = da.dbsetObject2.Where(p=>p.ID.Contains(listObject1.Object1ID)).ToList();
```

I know contains doesn't work but I want to basically populate listObject2 with all the values that have a matching Object1ID. In a sql table this would be a foreign key relationship.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq query list contains a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364090/linq-query-list-contains-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Based on updated information in comments

```
var lstObject1 = listObject1.Select(item -> item.ObjectId).ToArray();  
List<Object2> listObject2 = da.dbsetObject2.Where(p=> lstObject1.Contains(p.ObjectId)).ToList();
```

---

**Original**

Question is not clear from the code

Assuming, you cant p.ID in List, resulting query is

```
  List<Object2> listObject2 = da.dbsetObject2.Where(p=> listObject1.Contains(p.ID)).ToList();
```

Comment: This seems to be what I want. I need to test it in my code however. The only change I had to make was instead of using p.ID I passed p.Object1

Comment: I'm getting an error on listObject1 "The best overloaded method match for has some invalid arguments"

Comment: is datatype of p.Object1 not Object1? In that case Cast operator will be required. Post datatype of Object1 in the question.

Comment: Object1 and Object2 are classes. they contain ints, strings etc. They should join on Object1.Object1ID == Object2.Object1ID.

Comment: This option worked very well and in fact worked better than the .Include I found would work. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Then [`join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join.aspx) the two lists:

```
var results = from l2 in listObject2
              join l1 in listObject1 on l2.ID equals l1.Object1ID
              select new{anonymous type}
```

Comment: That seems like I need to populate listObject2 first and then populate the results I want into a 3rd variable. Is that correct?

Comment: @Bryce, Yes, or you can join the two `da.dbsetObject1`, `da.dbsetObject2` directly with the conditions you want to add to restrict your selection in these two lists.

Comment: My only concern is that as Object2's table gets larger then I'm populating a large object/slower SQL response times. There is no way to include the Object1IDs as a WHERE criteria like you would do in sql? I'm thinking of performance of bringing back large result sets from a sql server multiple times and then processing through them on an app server and how slow that could be verse having the sql server just bring back the smaller result set initially.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
//Populate first object
List<Object1> listObject1 = da.dbsetObject1.Where(p => p.ID.Equals(SomeID)).ToList();

//Populate second object - what I want to do but can't figure out
List<Object2> listObject2 = da.dbsetObject2.Where(p => listObject1.Any(q => q.ID == p.foreignID)).ToList();
```

**UPDATE**

```
void SomeMethod(){
      var arr = new Object1[]{
            new Object1{Name="n1",ID=1},
            new Object1{Name="n2",ID=2},
            new Object1{Name="n3",ID=3},
            new Object1{Name="n4",ID=4}
        };

        var arr2 = new Object2[]{
            new Object2{Name="o1", Ref=1},
            new Object2{Name="o2", Ref=2},
            new Object2{Name="o3", Ref=1},
            new Object2{Name="o4", Ref=2},
            new Object2{Name="o5", Ref=5},
            new Object2{Name="o6", Ref=3},
            new Object2{Name="o7", Ref=5}
        };

        List<Object1> listObject1 = arr.Where(p => p.ID == 1 || p.ID == 2).ToList();

        List<Object2> listObject2 = arr2.Where(p =>listObject1.Any(q => p.Ref == q.ID)).ToList();
}

    class Object1
    {
        public string Name;
        public int ID;
    }
    class Object2
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Ref;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this technique but the q in the listobject2 is erroring. It errors saying cannot convert lambda expression to type Object1 because it is not a delegate type

Comment: @Bryce Sorry, I forgot to use the Any extension method instead of Contains since Contains doesn't support lambdas. I'll update my answer with a full working example.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the best approach for what I am trying to do. Here is the code I needed:

```
var NewObject = da.dbsetObject1.Include("listObject2").ToList();
```

Then I can use NewObject as a list, and when I need an Object2 value associated with a particular Object1 value I can grab it.

Here are the classes:

```
public class Object1
{
    [Key]
    public int Object1ID { get; set; }
    .....
    public int Object2ID { get; set; }
    public List<Object2> listObject2 { get; set; }
}

public class Object2
{
    [Key]
    public int Object2ID { get; set; }
.....
public int Object1ID { get; set; }
    public Object2 myObject2 { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks everyone for the help! I wish a lambda expression had worked it looks a lot cleaner especially once I start adding more includes.