# how to check if the list with the same values exists

Tags: c#

In these following code segment::

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   List<List<int>> bigList = new List<List<int>> { };
   bigList.Add(new List<int> { 1, 2 });
   bigList.Add(new List<int> { 2, 3 });
   bigList.Add(new List<int> { 3, 4 });
   List<int> subList = new List<int> { 1, 2 };    
   Console.WriteLine(bigList.Contains(subList));
}
```

the output is:: 'False'.
then what is the method to check this. i mean how will the output become 'True'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq query list contains a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364090/linq-query-list-contains-a-list)

Comment: The correct question would be - how to check if the list with the same values exists.

Comment: Hint: `bigList.Any(inner => Enumerable.SequentialEquals(inner, subList))`

Comment: This requirement looks a bit weird. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

If the order doesn't matter you can use `Any`+`All`:

```
bool anyContains = bigList
    .Any(l => bigList.Count == l.Count && l.All(i => subList.Contains(i)));
```

Otherwise you can use `Any` + `SequenceEqual`

```
bool anySequencequals = bigList.Any(l => l.SequenceEqual(subList));
```

Comment: Your first example will also return `true` if `subList` is a superset of some `bigList` entry (e.g. `subList` is `{1, 2, 3}`), which is probably not what the OP intended.

Comment: Your fisrt solution doesn't cover all the cases. If `subList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 4 };` the answer will be `true` even if no list contains all the elements from `subList`.

Comment: @Heinzi: Good point, edited my answer to include the `Count`.

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking at your solution again, but this will consider `{ 1, 2, 2 }` and `{ 1, 1, 2 }` to be equal.

Comment: OP has not mentioned that he wants to check if two lists are equal. He wants to check if a second list contains all items of the first. At least this suggests his title. However, you are right, the question is not that clear and you have a valid point.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about duplicate entries in the lists you can use:

```
bigList.Any(b => new HashSet<int>(b).SetEquals(subList))
```

If you want both lists to contain exactly the same elements you can use this:

```
bigList.Any(b => b.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(subList.OrderBy(x => x)))
```

If you want both lists to have the same elements in the same order you can use this:

```
bigList.Any(x => x.SequenceEqual(subList))
```

Comment: thanks david. your answer is the most perfect according to my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `All` linq statement

```
var result = bigList.Where(x => x.All(y => subList.Contains(y)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) method to check with `Any`:

```
bigList.Any(x => x.SequenceEqual(subList))
```

Comment: Or, if you take it in the other order, you can do without a lambda: `bigList.Any(subList.SequenceEqual)`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your code returns "false" is because you are testing if bigList contains subList. Which it does not! BigList contains a list that looks the same as subList but isn't THE subList.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SequenceEqual` and `Any`:

```
bigList.Any(c => c.SequenceEqual(subList));
```

Or, if you want to use the other way, with `Contains`, you'll need to make a custom `EqualityComparer`:

```
public class CollectionEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    public Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y) 
    { 
        return x.SequenceEqual(y); 
    }
    public GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> obj) 
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return obj.Select(x => x.GetHashCode())
                      .Aggregate(17, (a, b) => a * 31 * b);
        }
    }
}
```

And then just use `Contains` like this:

```
bigList.Contains(sublist, new CollectionEqualityComparer<int>());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

> bigList.Add(subList);

**Complete Code**

```
        List<List<int>> bigList = new List<List<int>> { };
        List<int> subList = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
        bigList.Add(subList); //<<<<<<<<<< Here goes  Now bigList   contains subList    
        bigList.Add(new List<int> { 2, 3 });
        bigList.Add(new List<int> { 3, 4 });
        Console.WriteLine(bigList.Contains(subList));// true
```