# LINQ query to find if all items in list 2 are contained in list 1

Tags: c#, linq

I was trying to follow and then extend an old example, [Linq query list contains a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364090/linq-query-list-contains-a-list), but it didn't work for me.

```
class Part
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        {
            List<int> L1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
            List<int> L2 = new List<int> { 4, 3 };

            bool t = L2.Where(p => L2.All(q => L1.Contains(q))).Any();
        }



        {
            List<Part> L1 = new List<Part> { new Part { id = 1 }, new Part { id = 2 }, new Part { id = 3 }, new Part { id = 4 } };
            List<Part> L2 = new List<Part> { new Part { id = 3 }, new Part { id = 4 } };

            bool u = L2.Where(p => L2.All(q => L1.Contains(q.id))).Any();
        }
    }
}
```

The first test works for me but doesn't exactly match the earlier code I found. My second test has a syntax error at "L1.Contains(q.id)". I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L1` is a `List<Part>`, `q` is a `Part`, `q.id` is an int.

`L1` cannot `Contain` an item of type `int`

To check if `L1` contains an item with that ID, use `Any`

```
L2.All(q => L1.Any(e => e.id == q.id))
```

Comment: My first question on StackOverflow and an answer <10 minutes. This is fantastic. I used "bool u = L2.Where(p => L2.All(q => L1.Any(e => e.id == q.id))).Any()" and I think it does what I need.

Comment: bool u = L2.All(q => L1.Any(e => e.id == q.id)); is better. My "where" isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the equality operator you are checking to see if the lists contain references to the same objects. If you want to match then you have to do something like you did by choosing which values to compare on. Your syntax error is coming from the fact that you are comparing ids to Parts. If you project L1 to the ids (`L1.Select(p => p.Id)`) you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

For "IsContained" question:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    class Part
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        {
            var L1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
            var L2 = new List<int> { 4, 3 };

            bool t = L2.All(l2 => L1.Contains(l2));

            Console.WriteLine("L1 contains L2: {0}", t);
        }

        {
            var L1 = new List<Part> { new Part { id = 1 }, new Part { id = 2 }, new Part { id = 3 }, new Part { id = 4 } };
            var L2 = new List<Part> { new Part { id = 3 }, new Part { id = 4 } };

            bool u = L2.All(l2 => L1.Any(l1 => l1.id == l2.id));

            Console.WriteLine("L1 contains L2: {0}", u);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Contains` there because the type is a `List<Part>`, at least not without some kind of projection or a different argument. If you're going to commonly be intersecting lists with these types I recommend implementing `IEquatable<T>` for part like so;

```
class Part : IEquatable<Part>
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Part other)
    {

        //Check whether the compared object is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;

        //Check whether the compared object references the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

        //Check whether the products' properties are equal.
        return id.Equals(other.id) && name.Equals(other.name);
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {

        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null.
        int nameHash = name == null ? 0 : name.GetHashCode();

        int idHash = id.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the part.
        return nameHash ^ idHash;
    }
}
```

In doing so you can simply do `L1.Intersect(L2)` and get the expected results. If you're just going to do this once probably simpler to write something like; `L2.All(q => L1.Any(e => e.id == q.id))` though I wouldn't recommend repeated use of that in place of `Intersect`.

Comment: I started with Intersect() but a co-worker suggested there might be a better way which got me looking.

Comment: @DustyB better depends on your needs. I expect what you're using to have substantially worse performance so as I noted in the answer, it's good if you're doing the operation once, if you're using it frequently it's a bad shortcut to take.